# Not showing css styles in scene builder in javafx

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am putting styles in CSS file and import it correctly in fxml file, but styles are not showing in scene builder. But when I run the app all the styles are applied correctly. I am using intelijIdea Can someone please help me

Comment: Is the path of the CSS valid when the fxml recides in the resource(?) directory? How did you define specify the path in the fxml?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I believe certain names aren't picked up on, it seems.

For example, when I use the name, "content" for a class, or "title", those classes will not show up in the list of available class styles to apply to components. This seems like a silly, arbitrary thing to not even remotely document, but as far as I can tell, that was my issue.